# Reuse Factory_Girl generated list in multiple scenarios in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, factory-bot

I am using the FactoryGirl gem to generate a set of instances of my model for testing using capybara. Currently, the tests are checking to see if the filters work. The first test passes, however the second test does not.

This is the apply_filters.rb with the tests to run:

```
describe "applying filters to the scotland list" do 

 scenario "i apply a minimum income filter" do    
    charities = FactoryGirl.create_list(:scotland, 9)
    visit "/scotsfilter"
    fill_in('Minimum Income', :with => 5)
    click_button('Apply Filters')
    expect(page).to have_no_content(charities[0].Charity_Number)
    expect(page).to have_content(charities[5].Charity_Number)
    expect(page).to have_content(charities[6].Charity_Number)  
 end
 scenario "i apply a maximum income filter" do
    charities = FactoryGirl.create_list(:scotland, 9)
    visit "/scotsfilter"
    fill_in('Maximum Income', :with => 5)
    click_button('Apply Filters')
    expect(page).to have_content(charities[0].Charity_Number)
    expect(page).to have_no_content(charities[5].Charity_Number)
    expect(page).to have_no_content(charities[6].Charity_Number)  
  end
end
```

This is the Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :scotland do
    sequence(:id) {|n| n} 
    sequence(:Charity_Number){|n| "MyString#{n} "}
    Charity_Name "MyString"
    Registered_Date "MyString"
    Known_As "MyString"
    Charity_Status "MyString"
    Postcode "MyString"
    Constitutional_Form "MyString"
    Previous_Constitutional_Form_1 "MyString"
    Geographical_Spread "MyString"
    Main_Operating_Location "MyString"
    sequence(:Purposes){|n| "MyString#{n}"}
    sequence(:Beneficiaries){|n| "MyString#{n}"}
    Activities "MyString"
    Objectives "MyString"
    Principal_Office_Trustees_Address "MyString"
    Website "MyString"
    sequence(:Most_recent_year_income){|n| n}
    sequence(:Most_recent_year_expenditure){|n| n}
    Mailing_cycle "MyString"
    Year_end "MyString"
    Parent_charity_name "MyString"
    Parent_charity_number "MyString"
    Parent_charity_country_of_registration "MyString"
    Designated_religious_body "MyString"
    Regulatory_type "MyString"
  end
end
```

The second `FactoryGirl.create_list(:scotland,9)` however, generates a set of instances from `MyString10` to `MyString19`. I want it to use the original `MyString1` to `MyString9`. Ive tried global variables and placing the `charities` definition everywhere. What am i missing so that I can use `charities` in a series of upcoming tests?

Comment: If the income is what matters for the test - you should be specifying it when creating the objects, not trying to reset the sequences.

Comment: Does that not defeat the point of using a factory though? I could just specify new records for every test but I thought using a factory would be more efficient. Thank you.

Comment: The factory makes setting up the attributes not being tested easy - by specifying the attributes you are testing it makes it much clearer what the test is actually doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse the same objects in multiple tests, the database is cleared between each test specifically to isolate one test from another.  Additionally if a specific value of the created object is what matters for a given test you should be specifying that value when creating the object(s) and let the factory handle the values that don't matter

Therefore in your example tests you probably want something like

```
charities = (1..9).map {|income| FactoryGirl.create(:scotland, Most_recent_year_income: income }
```